# StackOver.in. Is it a Scam?

Tags: discussion, seo

I think this should be something to talk about. I was Google Searching some topic when I came across some answers on StackOverflow. When I clicked on another question, I've got redirected to some ads. Then, I've noticed that I was not on StackOverflow.

`http://stackover.in/questions/tagged/spam-prevention`

How can we address this problem? If there is any thing to do. If they copy the StackOverflow, they could be really high on Search Engines searches. I don't know what happens if someone clicks on login, but this could lead to some spam and creepy things.

What can we do?

Comment: It is a blatant copyright violation on the site design.  This is something that SE needs to take care of.  They don't have to go far btw, the pings where suspiciously quick.  While it looks like a site in India, it is actually owned by Edison Shaver who harks from the state of Indiana, USA :)

Comment: Thank you, Bjorn and Hans. I will follow the procedures on the topic linked above.

Comment: Done. It was reported. Thanks!